# How do I filter WFS GetFeature results?

Tags: wfs, getfeature, feature-filter

I am new to GIS. I am trying to work out how I can return a limited set of results for the WFS GetFeature query.

For instance, what is the URL to only return results where the ADD_POSTCODE is 3350 ? How do I even know I can query on ADD_POSTCODE versus the other data returned?

See http://services.land.vic.gov.au/catalogue/publicproxy/guest/dv_geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&request=GetFeature&typeName=datavic:VMPROP_PROPERTY_ADDRESS

```
<wfs:member>
<datavic:VMPROP_PROPERTY_ADDRESS gml:id="VMPROP_PROPERTY_ADDRESS.fid-ecced5e_17afd09cd9b_5e06">
<datavic:PROP_PFI>50292997</datavic:PROP_PFI>
<datavic:PROP_LGA_CODE>302</datavic:PROP_LGA_CODE>
<datavic:PROP_PROPNUM>2031609</datavic:PROP_PROPNUM>
<datavic:PROP_STATUS>A</datavic:PROP_STATUS>
<datavic:PROP_UFI>90502792</datavic:PROP_UFI>
<datavic:PROP_UFI_CREATED>2000-03-23T14:55:41Z</datavic:PROP_UFI_CREATED>
<datavic:PROPV_PFI>3264781</datavic:PROPV_PFI>
<datavic:PROPV_GRAPHIC_TYPE>P</datavic:PROPV_GRAPHIC_TYPE>
<datavic:ADD_PFI>51288123</datavic:ADD_PFI>
<datavic:ADD_EZI_ADDRESS>1/18A TALBOT STREET N BALLARAT CENTRAL 3350</datavic:ADD_EZI_ADDRESS>
<datavic:ADD_IS_PRIMARY>Y</datavic:ADD_IS_PRIMARY>
<datavic:ADD_STATE>VIC</datavic:ADD_STATE>
<datavic:ADD_POSTCODE>3350</datavic:ADD_POSTCODE>
<datavic:ADD_LOCALITY_NAME>BALLARAT CENTRAL</datavic:ADD_LOCALITY_NAME>
<datavic:ADD_NUM_ROAD_ADDRESS>1/18A TALBOT STREET N</datavic:ADD_NUM_ROAD_ADDRESS>
<datavic:ADD_UFI_CREATED>2010-11-16T06:42:37Z</datavic:ADD_UFI_CREATED>
<datavic:ADD_LABEL_ADDRESS>Y</datavic:ADD_LABEL_ADDRESS>
<datavic:ADD_HOUSE_NUMBER_1>18</datavic:ADD_HOUSE_NUMBER_1>
<datavic:ADD_ROAD_NAME>TALBOT</datavic:ADD_ROAD_NAME>
<datavic:ADD_ROAD_TYPE>STREET</datavic:ADD_ROAD_TYPE>
<datavic:ADD_ROAD_SUFFIX>N</datavic:ADD_ROAD_SUFFIX>
<datavic:ADD_BLG_UNIT_TYPE>UNIT</datavic:ADD_BLG_UNIT_TYPE>
<datavic:ADD_NUM_ADDRESS>1/18A</datavic:ADD_NUM_ADDRESS>
<datavic:SHAPE>
<gml:MultiSurface srsDimension="2" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4283">
<gml:surfaceMember>
<gml:Polygon srsDimension="2">
<gml:exterior>
<gml:LinearRing>
<gml:posList>-37.55884259 143.84385041 -37.55885219 143.84394062 -37.55879233 143.84395169 -37.55878595 143.84389218 -37.55876173 143.84368693 -37.55875241 143.84361651 -37.55874023 143.84351047 -37.55873136 143.84343743 -37.55872455 143.84338679 -37.55879185 143.84337436 -37.55880871 143.84341315 -37.55883363 143.84363398 -37.55882924 143.84363489 -37.55883433 143.84368118 -37.55881649 143.84368436 -37.55883158 143.84382423 -37.55884259 143.84385041</gml:posList>
</gml:LinearRing>
</gml:exterior>
</gml:Polygon>
</gml:surfaceMember>
</gml:MultiSurface>
</datavic:SHAPE>
</datavic:VMPROP_PROPERTY_ADDRESS>
</wfs:member>
```

Comment: What have you tried? You can add an OGC filter or a CQL filter to your request

Comment: I haven't tried anything, not even sure how to use GIS as I don't know how it is documented. Is there a tutorial for it somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using cql_filter and it's working e.g http://services.land.vic.gov.au/catalogue/publicproxy/guest/dv_geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&request=GetFeature&typeName=datavic:VMPROP_PROPERTY_ADDRESS&cql_filter=datavic%3AADD_POSTCODE%3D3350

Response quite slow but related to the server it seems.

You will also need to paginate as limit is 5000 features from this server

Answer (score 1):

> How do I even know I can query on ADD_POSTCODE versus the other data returned?

First you run GetCapabilities request to discover the capabilities of the particular server; such as operations supported, filters supported, feature types provided, extents of data, crs supported for data etc.

```
http://services.land.vic.gov.au/catalogue/publicproxy/guest/dv_geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities
```

For any feature type you want more information on you run a DescribeFeatureType request:

```
http://services.land.vic.gov.au/catalogue/publicproxy/guest/dv_geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typename=datavic:VMPROP_PROPERTY_ADDRESS&

<xsd:schema xmlns:datavic="http://land.vic.gov.au/datavic" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://land.vic.gov.au/datavic">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="http://services.land.vic.gov.au/catalogue/publicproxy/guest/dv_geoserver/schemas/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="VMPROP_PROPERTY_ADDRESSType">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PROP_PFI" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PROP_LGA_CODE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PROP_PROPNUM" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PROP_STATUS" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="PROP_UFI" nillable="false" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PROP_UFI_CREATED" nillable="true" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="PROPV_PFI" nillable="false" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PROPV_GRAPHIC_TYPE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADD_PFI" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADD_EZI_ADDRESS" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADD_IS_PRIMARY" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADD_STATE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADD_POSTCODE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADD_LOCALITY_NAME" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADD_NUM_ROAD_ADDRESS" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADD_UFI_CREATED" nillable="true" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADD_LABEL_ADDRESS" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADD_HOUSE_NUMBER_1" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADD_HOUSE_NUMBER_2" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADD_DISP_NUMBER_1" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADD_DISP_NUMBER_2" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADD_ROAD_NAME" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADD_ROAD_TYPE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADD_ROAD_SUFFIX" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADD_BUILDING_NAME" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADD_BLG_UNIT_TYPE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADD_NUM_ADDRESS" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SHAPE" nillable="true" type="gml:MultiSurfacePropertyType"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element name="VMPROP_PROPERTY_ADDRESS" substitutionGroup="gml:AbstractFeature" type="datavic:VMPROP_PROPERTY_ADDRESSType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Will give you the properties that can be queried.

To find out how many features will be returned for any query try a GetFeature request with `resultType=hits&` specified:

```
http://services.land.vic.gov.au/catalogue/publicproxy/guest/dv_geoserver/ows?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typeNames=datavic:VMPROP_PROPERTY_ADDRESS&resultType=hits&version=2.0.0

<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" numberMatched="5000" numberReturned="0" timeStamp="2021-11-30T16:13:02.393Z" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd"/>
```

**numberMatched="5000"**

Alternatively restrict the response to a count of 1 feature:

```
http://services.land.vic.gov.au/catalogue/publicproxy/guest/dv_geoserver/ows?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typeNames=datavic:VMPROP_PROPERTY_ADDRESS&version=2.0.0&count=1&

<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:datavic="http://land.vic.gov.au/datavic" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" numberMatched="3973206" numberReturned="1" timeStamp="2021-11-30T16:18:18.154Z" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd http://land.vic.gov.au/datavic http://services.land.vic.gov.au/catalogue/publicproxy/guest/dv_geoserver/datavic/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=datavic%3AVMPROP_PROPERTY_ADDRESS">
    <wfs:member>
        <datavic:VMPROP_PROPERTY_ADDRESS gml:id="VMPROP_PROPERTY_ADDRESS.fid-38c0f02d_17d70c6425c_63af">
        <datavic:PROP_PFI>45247081</datavic:PROP_PFI>
        <datavic:PROP_LGA_CODE>302</datavic:PROP_LGA_CODE>
        <datavic:PROP_PROPNUM>2024258</datavic:PROP_PROPNUM>
        <datavic:PROP_STATUS>A</datavic:PROP_STATUS>
        <datavic:PROP_UFI>90490965</datavic:PROP_UFI>
        <datavic:PROP_UFI_CREATED>2000-03-23T13:33:31Z</datavic:PROP_UFI_CREATED>
        <datavic:PROPV_PFI>4308636</datavic:PROPV_PFI>
        <datavic:PROPV_GRAPHIC_TYPE>P</datavic:PROPV_GRAPHIC_TYPE>
        <datavic:ADD_PFI>53869297</datavic:ADD_PFI>
        <datavic:ADD_EZI_ADDRESS>104 NELSON STREET BALLARAT EAST 3350</datavic:ADD_EZI_ADDRESS>
        <datavic:ADD_IS_PRIMARY>Y</datavic:ADD_IS_PRIMARY>
        <datavic:ADD_STATE>VIC</datavic:ADD_STATE>
        <datavic:ADD_POSTCODE>3350</datavic:ADD_POSTCODE>
        <datavic:ADD_LOCALITY_NAME>BALLARAT EAST</datavic:ADD_LOCALITY_NAME>
        <datavic:ADD_NUM_ROAD_ADDRESS>104 NELSON STREET</datavic:ADD_NUM_ROAD_ADDRESS>
        <datavic:ADD_UFI_CREATED>2008-07-23T05:23:01Z</datavic:ADD_UFI_CREATED>
        <datavic:ADD_LABEL_ADDRESS>Y</datavic:ADD_LABEL_ADDRESS>
        <datavic:ADD_HOUSE_NUMBER_1>104</datavic:ADD_HOUSE_NUMBER_1>
        <datavic:ADD_ROAD_NAME>NELSON</datavic:ADD_ROAD_NAME>
        <datavic:ADD_ROAD_TYPE>STREET</datavic:ADD_ROAD_TYPE>
        <datavic:ADD_NUM_ADDRESS>104</datavic:ADD_NUM_ADDRESS>
        <datavic:SHAPE>
            <gml:MultiSurface srsDimension="2" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4283">
                <gml:surfaceMember>
                    <gml:Polygon srsDimension="2">
                        <gml:exterior>
                            <gml:LinearRing>
                                <gml:posList>-37.5574846 143.87664653 -37.55724458 143.87651263 -37.55728739 143.87639191 -37.55749919 143.87651026 -37.5574846 143.87664653</gml:posList>
                            </gml:LinearRing>
                        </gml:exterior>
                    </gml:Polygon>
                </gml:surfaceMember>
            </gml:MultiSurface>
        </datavic:SHAPE>
        </datavic:VMPROP_PROPERTY_ADDRESS>
    </wfs:member>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

**numberMatched="3973206"**

To get all results you would need to page through by adding a startindex=[some number]&count=[some number]&

> I don't know how it is documented.

A good place to start is the OGC specification

https://www.ogc.org/standards/wfs